# How do I let database/sql query multiple schemas in parallel?

Tags: mysql, go, schema

I have mysql database with single host and a few hundred schemas, where each schemas have identical tables (and different amount of rows). What I want to do here is to query some (or all) schemas with same list of queries, and save these result for later use.
I'm using golang's `database/sql` for querying database, and I want to do that with single connection pool, and by querying each schemas in parallel (hoping it's faster that way).
I'm imagining something like this:

```golang
func QuerySchemas(queryList []string, schemaList []string) {
  // Create a connection pool
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(db_host)/")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  for _, schema := range schemaList {
    // Query each schema in parallel, probably with goroutine
    go func(targetSchema string) {
      // ...
      // Let database/sql use targetSchema for this goroutine
      // ...
      for _, query := range queryList {
        rows, err := db.Query(query)
        // ...
        // Save results and do other things
        // ...
      } 
    }(schema) 
  }
}
```

But I can't find how to let `database/sql` query different schemas in parallel. So far I have thought of using MySQL's `USE` sentences, but that would not work as it changes schema for all goroutines.
Is there any possible solutions?

Comment: Have you considered using fmt to interpolate the schema into the query? e.g. `query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s.table_name ...", targetSchema)` etc.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I have once considered doing that. I had no idea how should I implement that though, perhaps there is a parser good for that task?

Comment: There is nothing to implement, just update the queries you want to execute by adding the fmt verbs/placeholders where you want the schema name to be inserted and then before execution pass each query to Sprtinf passing in the schema as the second argument, pass the output of that to db.Query and you're done.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the idea -- I'll try if that works later.